# Adjusted proxy settings in Create-React-App to get around CORS blocking error and now get an undefined response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, cors, create-react-app

I'm having issues after adding a work-around for CORS blocking a request within Create-React-App.

As recommended I have updated the proxy settings to the same domain I am trying to call in my package.json (example with dummy data)

```
"proxy": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
```

and make the call in my App.js file as follows..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/posts/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data));
  });
  return <div className="App">Returned here</div>;
}

export default App;
```

I don't get the CORS error anymore, which is good, however I do get the following error message

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tested the API in postman and its all returning correctly so not sure where the issue is.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code sandbox doesn't seem to be using `create-react-app` out of the box.

From looking at the code:

```
    fetch("/posts/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data));
```

Should be adjusted to

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/posts")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setProducts(data);
      });
  }, []);
```